# Django-admin AttributeError:

Tags: python, django, cryptography, django-admin

I've just started learning how to use django for some school projects.I installed django with pip but when I try to start a project with `django-admin startproject abc` I get error:

```
      File "c:\users\user\.virtualenvs\project-gnrbo21b\lib\site-packages\django\utils\crypto.py", line 74, in <genexpr>
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(allowed_chars) for i in range(length)) 
AttributeError: module 'secrets' has no attribute 'choice'
```

I can't find any solutions on internet, any ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: Go into an interactive shell (with the same interpreter you are running django on ) and type `import secrets; help(secrets)`, what does it say? It must  say something along the lines of **Generate cryptographically ...**.

Comment: As someone new to Django myself, I get a lot of "module 'xyz' has no attribute 'abc'" and I've learned that it relates to the disconnect among the 3 files: the html (template) file, views.py, and urls.py. Check the spelling and names--and check the location of the template file. Is it in the folder it's supposed to be in?

Answer (score 0):

Each django version supports some corresponded python version. For example latest 3.1.* version supports Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, and 3.9 ([details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.1/))